# Is there any reason to bundle custom CSS files together in a Multi-Page Application?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Take this basic multi-page application structure that uses webpack to bundle common Javascript into `vendor.js` and shared CSS styles into a `main.css`:

**[PAGE].html**

```
<link href="css/main.css" />
<link href="css/[PAGE]_custom.css" />
CONTENT
<script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
```

Each pages would be similar, just with their own unique `[PAGE]_custom.css`. Is there a reason for these `[]_custom.css` files to even be processed by webpack?

It seems inefficient to add in a new `entry` every time you want to add styling to a new page. Also wouldn't the `.css` files have conflicts with each other when they are bundled? In addition, if caching is a concern, making a small change in the CSS of one file would change the hash of the bundle, requiring another download.

I quite a few webpack tutorial/walk-through's that put a huge emphasis on "*bundle all the things*". Am I thinking about Webpack incorrectly? Or is there a different way to configure Webpack to handle multi-page applications?